# Efficient methods to store and apply relationships defined by formulas?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have a set of tables that are updated regularly such that batch processing calculations are not ideal.  The columns in the tables can be combined to produce metrics but each table uses a different combination of columns for each metric. Not all tables share all metrics.

For example, say there is table T1 and T2 with the following columns.

```
T1 (A, B, C, D)
T2 (Q, R, S, T)
```

And some metrics such that

```
Table Metric Formula
T1    M1     A+B
T2    M1     R
T1    M2     C-D
T2    M2     (S+Q)/T
T1    M3     B*C
T2    M4     T
```

My current thoughts are to create a table similar to the above and use dynamic SQL in a stored procedure to calculate the needed metrics when they are requested.  Imagine another table defining datasets by sets of table-metric pairs.

Is there a more efficient (by SQL lines to construct the query and readability for other coders) way to go about this?

I know SQL Server can store JSON and XML but it seems to me that simply storing the formula's as strings would do.  I am also considering an insert/update trigger to calculate and store the metrics to a table as the data arrives/updates; trigger would need to be fast so as to not hold up the table.

Using SQL Server 2016

Comment: What about adding computed columns? How often are these metrics/formulas added or changed?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ The tables are already quiet wide and I would like to avoid making them wider. It would also make collecting the defined datasets more tedious as I would have hardcode columns into a query that spans across tables for each defined dataset.  With my current idea I can store all the metrics in one table from all  source tables and collect any dataset from one simple join; perhaps with a table-valued function taking the dataset id.

Comment: Are requests going to come in for previously unknown combinations of Metrics, e.g. Give me T1.M1, T1.M3? Are the tables T1/T2 etc related or just separate examples that will be queried separately?

Comment: @MisterMagoo Yes, new request will come in over time for new metrics and new metric datasets. Metric datasets do span the tables, e.g. give me T1.M2 and T2.M4.  The same metric can be requested from multiple tables (some tables hold "better" measurements than other tables.

Comment: Why do you need to create tables to store these calculations? Why not just have a view that performs the calculations? Do you already know the calculations will be too expensive to perform at runtime, and that the triggers won't offset that and more?